# Linux server rebooting automatically

Tags: linux

Here is the syslog of my linux server which is restarting itself in intervals for a month. I am not being able to find the reason till now. Could anyone help me understand why the sever took a restart today and what can i do to stop it. The restarts are not good for my work.
Thank you in advance.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w94zi.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygGum.png)

```
root@ANTSServer02:~# last -n 10 -Fwi
root     pts/0        192.168.1.17     Tue Apr 27 08:04:36 2021   still logged in
reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Tue Apr 27 07:54:48 2021   still running
root     pts/0        192.168.1.17     Mon Apr 26 07:56:04 2021 - Mon Apr 26 18:13:52 2021  (10:17)
reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Sun Apr 25 11:09:20 2021   still running
reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Fri Apr 23 14:21:02 2021   still running
root     pts/0        192.168.1.17     Tue Apr 20 08:08:58 2021 - Tue Apr 20 14:25:18 2021  (06:16)
root     pts/0        192.168.1.17     Mon Apr 19 10:57:32 2021 - Mon Apr 19 17:43:04 2021  (06:45)
root     pts/0        192.168.1.17     Mon Apr 19 07:56:40 2021 - Mon Apr 19 10:47:19 2021  (02:50)
reboot   system boot  0.0.0.0          Fri Apr 16 22:04:36 2021   still running
root     pts/0        192.168.1.17     Mon Apr 12 13:32:33 2021 - Mon Apr 12 15:23:25 2021  (01:50)
```

```
root@ANTSServer02:~# dmesg | grep EXT4 -U3
[    2.045615] hid-generic 0003:045E:0040.0003: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Microsoft Microsoft 3-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM)] on usb-0000:00:14.0-7/input0
[    2.119560] fbcon: Taking over console
[    2.119675] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[    2.305443] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[    2.363274] systemd[1]: Inserted module 'autofs4'
[    2.478026] systemd[1]: systemd 245.4-4ubuntu3.5 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN2 -IDN +PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[    2.496174] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
--
[    2.650424] systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Trace File System.
[    2.651028] systemd[1]: Finished Create list of static device nodes for the current kernel.
[    2.651587] systemd[1]: Finished Uncomplicated firewall.
[    2.656413] EXT4-fs (nvme0n1p2): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[    2.656676] RPC: Registered named UNIX socket transport module.
[    2.656677] RPC: Registered udp transport module.
[    2.656677] RPC: Registered tcp transport module.
```

```
Apr 27 07:27:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[433520]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:28:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[433629]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:28:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[433630]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:29:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[433740]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:29:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[433741]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:30:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[433851]: (root) CMD ([ -x /etc/init.d/anacron ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/sbin/invoke-rc.d anacron start >/dev/null; fi)
Apr 27 07:30:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[433852]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:30:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[433853]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:31:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[433960]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:31:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[433961]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:32:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[434068]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:32:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[434069]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:32:40 ANTSServer02 systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Apr 27 07:32:40 ANTSServer02 anacron[434151]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2021-04-27
Apr 27 07:32:40 ANTSServer02 anacron[434151]: Will run job `cron.daily' in 5 min.
Apr 27 07:32:40 ANTSServer02 anacron[434151]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
Apr 27 07:33:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[434182]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:33:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[434183]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:34:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[434291]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:34:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[434292]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:35:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[434409]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:35:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[434410]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:36:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[434519]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:36:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[434520]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:37:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[434629]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:37:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[434630]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:37:40 ANTSServer02 anacron[434151]: Job `cron.daily' started
Apr 27 07:37:40 ANTSServer02 anacron[434717]: Updated timestamp for job `cron.daily' to 2021-04-27
Apr 27 07:37:40 ANTSServer02 cracklib: no dictionary update necessary.
Apr 27 07:37:40 ANTSServer02 anacron[434151]: Job `cron.daily' terminated
Apr 27 07:37:40 ANTSServer02 anacron[434151]: Normal exit (1 job run)
Apr 27 07:37:40 ANTSServer02 systemd[1]: anacron.service: Succeeded.
Apr 27 07:38:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[434788]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:38:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[434789]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:39:00 ANTSServer02 systemd[1]: Starting Clean php session files...
Apr 27 07:39:00 ANTSServer02 systemd[1]: phpsessionclean.service: Succeeded.
Apr 27 07:39:00 ANTSServer02 systemd[1]: Finished Clean php session files.
Apr 27 07:39:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[434954]: (root) CMD (  [ -x /usr/lib/php/sessionclean ] && if [ ! -d /run/systemd/system ]; then /usr/lib/php/sessionclean; fi)
Apr 27 07:39:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[434955]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:39:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[434956]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:40:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[435070]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:40:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[435071]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:41:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[435178]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:41:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[435179]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:42:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[435295]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:42:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[435296]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:43:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[435409]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:43:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[435410]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:44:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[435519]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:44:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[435520]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:45:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[435630]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:45:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[435631]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:46:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[435740]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:46:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[435741]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:47:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[435849]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:47:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[435850]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:48:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[435964]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:48:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[435965]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:49:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[436076]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:49:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[436077]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:50:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[436187]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:50:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[436188]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:51:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[436297]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:51:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[436298]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:52:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[436414]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:52:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[436415]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:53:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[436528]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:53:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[436529]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:54:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[436639]: (www-data) CMD ($PASSBOLT_BASE_DIR/bin/cron)
Apr 27 07:54:01 ANTSServer02 CRON[436640]: (www-data) CMD (/var/www/passbolt/bin/cake EmailQueue.sender)
Apr 27 07:54:49 ANTSServer02 systemd-modules-load[320]: Inserted module 'lp'
```

```
root@ANTSServer02:~# sudo systemctl list-timers
NEXT                         LEFT           LAST                         PASSED       UNIT                         ACTIVATES
Fri 2021-04-30 09:09:00 CEST 8min left      Fri 2021-04-30 08:39:01 CEST 21min ago    phpsessionclean.timer        phpsessionclean.service
Fri 2021-04-30 09:34:45 CEST 34min left     Fri 2021-04-30 08:35:01 CEST 25min ago    anacron.timer                anacron.service
Fri 2021-04-30 16:46:48 CEST 7h left        Thu 2021-04-29 22:59:26 CEST 10h ago      motd-news.timer              motd-news.service
Fri 2021-04-30 19:08:59 CEST 10h left       Fri 2021-04-30 06:56:59 CEST 2h 3min ago  certbot.timer                certbot.service
Sat 2021-05-01 00:00:00 CEST 14h left       Fri 2021-04-30 00:00:01 CEST 9h ago       logrotate.timer              logrotate.service
Sat 2021-05-01 00:00:00 CEST 14h left       Fri 2021-04-30 00:00:01 CEST 9h ago       man-db.timer                 man-db.service
Sat 2021-05-01 03:22:49 CEST 18h left       Fri 2021-04-30 06:42:33 CEST 2h 17min ago apt-daily.timer              apt-daily.service
Sat 2021-05-01 06:38:54 CEST 21h left       Fri 2021-04-30 06:49:47 CEST 2h 10min ago apt-daily-upgrade.timer      apt-daily-upgrade.service
Sat 2021-05-01 07:32:42 CEST 22h left       Fri 2021-04-30 07:32:42 CEST 1h 27min ago systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
Sun 2021-05-02 03:10:41 CEST 1 day 18h left Sun 2021-04-25 03:10:39 CEST 5 days ago   e2scrub_all.timer            e2scrub_all.service
Mon 2021-05-03 00:00:00 CEST 2 days left    Mon 2021-04-26 00:00:01 CEST 4 days ago   fstrim.timer                 fstrim.service
```

Comment: logs *after* restart won't help (nor screenshots)

Comment: There is only cron jobs before the restart. What else can I send you so that I get some help

Comment: Logs from before the restart.  In text format, no pictures.  About the cron jobs: the restart may be scheduled.

Comment: Please, append an output of `last -n 10 -Fwi`. This reads `wtmp` file and it might give a clue why system was rebooted. Also, another machine could help in debugging by receiving logs over the network or/and console over the serial; your target server needs to have serial console and netconsole configured, which is easy.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov Thank you for your answer. I am using mobaxterm to see the logs.

Comment: Thank you for guiding @NikitaKipriyanov . new here

Comment: Check if `dmesg` shows any signs of previous unclean shudown, e.g. journal replay and other filesystem complaints during a boot. Just examine the output during a startup.

Comment: If you see from the output of last -n 10 -Fwi, there are reboot running from apr 16 and apr 25, is this something of concern ? I am trying to understand the dmesg to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: I see the reboots, these say either system was just properly rebooted, or the problem was so severe so it was unable even to update wtmp before a reboot. To discriminate between these cases you often see if file systems were cleanly unmounted or not. See `dmesg` output where it is mounting root file system. If you know which file system it is, you may filter it with grep. For example, for ext4 I'll try something like `dmesg | grep EXT4 -U3` to see some lines around the line, containing the word "EXT4". Note, it is just a happy coincidence that the filter string is file system name in capitals.

Comment: It might be soemthing serious surely. I have checked all possible reboot possibilites according to my knowledge and i dont know why it reboots now. 
I updated the new outcomes with file extension.
Thank you very much for taking your time and helping me understand

Comment: It sounds like the system is rebooting on a Kernel panic. Check for a non-zero value running `sysctl -n kernel.panic`.

Comment: Would you please also tell which is used distribution

Comment: @AaronCopleythe value is 0

Comment: @djdomi Linux version 5.8.0-48-generic (buildd@lgw01-amd64-008) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04) 9.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #54~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Sat Mar 20 13:40:25 UTC 2021

Comment: @AaronCopley what made you think it can be kernel panic ?

Comment: I strongly doubt this is panic. I see **no** signs of unclean shutdown; at least, the file system was mounted as if it was shut down cleanly. If the shutdown was abrupt, there must have been some journal replay during mount at boot, which is not present in the dmesg. @AbdulRazzak, please check `/var/log/syslog` and `messages` files, what's in the logs immediately before last `[    0.000000] Linux version...` line (or similar), which is the beginning of boot up.

Comment: I edited and put few lines from syslog. @NikitaKipriyanov

Comment: i would suggest to take a look to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/60574/determining-cause-of-linux-kernel-panic

Comment: Why it tried to load `lp` module long after boot was completed? What if you load it by hand, will it crash?

Comment: I wouldn't normally recommend it, but you could rename `/sbin/reboot` and `/sbin/poweroff` and then put a short script in place to capture details of anything trying to call either.

Is the server a VM, Is the hypervisor rebooting it? Is it in a UPS / is the power reliable ?

Comment: @AbdulRazzak I thought it could be a possibility and it was just something to check but you verified it's not with the zero value. Unless IPMI Watchdog or something is intervening. The fact that the last thing it's doing before reboot is inserting a module all but confirms it...

Comment: check your systemd timers: `sudo systemctl list-timers`.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov It loaded lp module during the reboot at 07:54:49. It was the time when the reboot started. I am sorry for the confusion. I shouldnt have copied this line.

Comment: @mforsetti I added the outcomes of this command

Comment: [`reboot` entry without `shutdown` entry in `last` marks an ungraceful shutdown](https://access.redhat.com/articles/2642741#last). do you have any old `dmesg` logs in `/var/log`?

Comment: @Timothyc the server is LENOVO_MT_30CY_BU_Think_FM_ThinkStation P330

Answer (score 0):

Look in cron jobs, if it´s programble restart every month. if not look in the performance and load of machine, this is what come to my head for moment.

Comment: The output of `last` does not indicate a predictable pattern of reboots as would happen if `cron` was doing the reboot.